Assembly Error with NASM: TIMES value -23 is negative
I am a newbie to Assembly and I got the following error:
src/bootloader/bootloader.asm:292: error: TIMES value -23 is negative
make: *** [build/bootloader.bin] Error 1

I'm trying to create a basic operating system. I tried solving the error by reducing number of lines, it reduced the number, but its impossible to reduce more.
This is my code:
bootloader.asm
org 0x7C00
bits 16

%define ENDL 0x0D, 0x0A

jmp short start
nop

bdb_oem:                    db 'MSWIN4.1'       
bdb_bytes_per_sector:       dw 512
bdb_sectors_per_cluster:    db 1
bdb_reserved_sectors:       dw 1
bdb_fat_count:              db 2
bdb_dir_entries_count:      dw 0E0h
bdb_total_sectors:          dw 2880                 
bdb_media_descriptor_type:  db 0F0h                 
bdb_sectors_per_fat:        dw 9 
bdb_sectors_per_track:      dw 18
bdb_heads:                  dw 2
bdb_hidden_sectors:         dd 0
bdb_large_sector_count:     dd 0

ebr_drive_number:           db 0
                            db 0
ebr_signature:              db 29h
ebr_volume_id:              db 12h, 34h, 56h, 78h
ebr_volume_label:           db 'BESTMAT OS' 
ebr_system_id:              db 'FAT12   '

start:
    jmp main

main:
    mov ax, 0
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax

    mov ss, ax
    mov sp, 0x7C00

    push es
    push word .after
    retf

.after:
    mov [ebr_drive_number], dl

    mov si, msg_hello
    call puts

    push es
    mov ah, 08h
    int 13h
    jc floppy_error
    pop es

    and cl, 0x3F
    xor ch, ch
    mov [bdb_sectors_per_track], cx

    inc dh
    mov [bdb_heads], dh

    mov ax, [bdb_sectors_per_fat]
    mov bl, [bdb_fat_count]
    xor bh, bh
    mul bx
    add ax, [bdb_reserved_sectors]
    push ax

    mov ax, [bdb_dir_entries_count]
    shl ax, 5
    xor dx, dx
    div word [bdb_bytes_per_sector]

    test dx, dx
    jz .root_dir_after
    inc ax

.root_dir_after:
    mov cl, al
    pop ax
    mov dl, [ebr_drive_number]
    mov bx, buffer
    call disk_read

    xor bx, bx
    mov di, buffer

.search_kernel:
    mov si, file_kernel_bin
    mov cx, 11
    push di
    repe cmpsb
    pop di
    je .found_kernel

    add di, 32
    inc bx
    cmp bx, [bdb_dir_entries_count]
    jl .search_kernel

    jmp kernel_not_found_error

.found_kernel:
    mov ax, [di + 26]
    mov [kernel_cluster], ax

    mov ax, [bdb_reserved_sectors]
    mov bx, buffer
    mov cl, [bdb_sectors_per_fat]
    mov dl, [ebr_drive_number]
    call disk_read

    mov bx, KERNEL_LOAD_SEGMENT
    mov es, bx
    mov bx, KERNEL_LOAD_OFFSET

.load_kernel_loop:
    mov ax, [kernel_cluster]
    add ax, 31
    mov cl, 1
    mov dl, [ebr_drive_number]
    call disk_read
    
    add bx, [bdb_bytes_per_sector]

    mov ax, [kernel_cluster]
    mov cx, 3
    mul cx
    mov cx, 2
    div cx

    mov si, buffer
    add si, ax
    mov ax, [ds:si]
    
    or dx, dx
    jz .even

.odd:
    shr ax, 4
    jmp .next_cluster_after

.even:
    and ax, 0x0FFF

.next_cluster_after:
    cmp ax, 0x0FF8
    jae .read_finish

    mov [kernel_cluster], ax
    jmp .load_kernel_loop

.read_finish:
    mov dl, [ebr_drive_number]
    mov ax, KERNEL_LOAD_SEGMENT
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax

    jmp KERNEL_LOAD_SEGMENT:KERNEL_LOAD_OFFSET

    jmp wait_key_and_reboot

    cli
    hlt

floppy_error:
    mov si, msg_read_failed
    call puts
    jmp wait_key_and_reboot

kernel_not_found_error:
    mov si, msg_kernel_not_found
    call puts
    jmp wait_key_and_reboot

wait_key_and_reboot:
    mov ah, 0
    int 16h            
    jmp 0FFFFh:0   

.halt:
    cli
    hlt

puts:
    push si
    push ax
    push bx

.loop:
    lodsb
    or al, al
    jz .done

    mov ah, 0x0E
    mov bh, 0
    int 0x10

    jmp .loop

.done:
    pop bx
    pop ax
    pop si    
    ret

lba_to_chs:
    push ax
    push dx

    xor dx, dx
    div word [bdb_sectors_per_track]    
                                        

    inc dx                              
    mov cx, dx                          

    xor dx, dx                          
    div word [bdb_heads]                
                                        
    mov dh, dl                          
    mov ch, al                          
    shl ah, 6
    or cl, ah                           

    pop ax
    mov dl, al                          
    pop ax
    ret

disk_read:
    push ax
    push bx
    push cx
    push dx
    push di

    push cx

    call lba_to_chs
    pop ax

    mov ah, 02h
    mov di, 3

.retry:
    pusha
    stc
    int 13h
    jnc .done
    popa
    call disk_reset
    dec di
    test di, di
    jnz .retry

.fail:
    jmp floppy_error

.done:
    popa

    pop di
    pop dx
    pop cx
    pop bx
    pop ax

    ret

disk_reset:
    pusha
    mov ah, 0
    stc
    int 13h
    jc floppy_error
    popa
    ret

msg_hello:                      db "Hello World!", ENDL, 0
msg_read_failed:                db "BESTMAT: Read from disk failed!", ENDL, 0
msg_kernel_not_found:           db "BESTMAT: KERNEL.BIN file not found!", ENDL, 0
file_kernel_bin:                db "KERNEL    BIN"
kernel_cluster:                 dw 0

KERNEL_LOAD_SEGMENT             equ 0x2000
KERNEL_LOAD_OFFSET              equ 0


times 510-($-$$)                db 0
dw 0AA55h

buffer:

I made this from a YouTube Tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7o3qx66uLz8&t=1165s
My question may be silly, I'm a newbie in this concept.
Thank you!
**EDIT: ** Now the number is -323 :(

Your code + data size is greater than 510 bytes.

Does this answer your question? How to Solve 'bootloader.asm:30: error: TIMES value -44 is negative' Problem in NASM
